# Form in Colorbox AJAX: after form submitted, I need Colorbox to close and the visitor redirected to results page

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, colorbox

I have a search form I'm going to have it in Colorbox.  The user will click on a link "Search" on any given page on the site, colorbox will open and frame a page with a search form in colorbox.  After the user submits the form, the problem is the form redirects to a new page but it is still in colorbox.  This is a problem b/c the search results page doesn't fit into Colorbox.  Instead, I'd prefer to have it so that when the user submits the form, colorbox closes and the user is redirected to the results page for the search results.

Thanks!

Comment: We need to see the ColorBox's iframe's form code, so we can tell you how to replicate it's function in the parent page.

Comment: Ah dang...sorry about this.  I did a few test runs and it turns out that Colorbox closes on it's own after form submission.  My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Colorbox closes upon submitting the form.  I should have tested before asking questions.  Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

You could possible do:

```
var form = $("colorbox > iframe").contents().find("form").clone();
form.appendTo("body").submit();
```